# Can an excessively deep C++ class hierarchy cause a stack overflow?

Tags: c++, stack, stack-overflow, distributed-computing, callstack

Suppose I have a C++ program that has excessively deep inheritance as follows:

```
using namespace std;

class AbstractParentGeneration0 {
    private:
      ...
    protected:
      ...
    public:
      virtual returnVal funcName(void) = 0;
};

class AbstractParentGeneration1: virtual public AbstractParentGeneration0 {
    private:
      ...
    protected:
      ...
    public:
      virtual returnVal funcName(void) = 0;
};

.
.
.

class AbstractParentGeneration999999999: virtual public AbstractParentGeneration999999998 {
    private:
      ...
    protected:
      ...
    public:
      virtual returnVal funcName(void) = 0;
};

class ChildGeneration: public AbstractParentGeneration999999999 {
    private:
      ...
    protected:
      ...
    public:
      returnVal funcName(void) { ... };
};
```

Suppose the nature of the program is such that the deep inheritance
can not be compacted (suppose it represents an evolutionary species
lineage or a deep taxonomy hierarchy)

Isn't there a stack overflow danger when calling the top abstract class?

What strategies (other than "ulimit -s bytes" or collapsing the
abstract hierarchy) do C++ programmers use to work within
system boundaries?

Is there a way to flatten a deep vertical inheritance hierarchy across
many host systems via RPC?

Do some people design their own call stack mechanism?

Is there such a thing as a distributed network / cluster call stack?

Comment: +1 for asking about StackOverflows

Comment: Take away the 'virtual' aspect of the inheritance and the sizeof() of the class does not change no matter how many bases it has underneath it (ignoring whatever user-defined data members there may be).

Comment: Why not just try it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your specific question, *no* there will be no danger of stack overflow at runtime when calling the top level abstract virtual method. Most implementations of C++ will have a vtable pointer entry in the object instance that points directly at the appropriate implementation function.

If you're curious about how this works, I recommend you write such a program with a few levels of hierarchy, and load up an assembly level debugger that shows you what is really going on.

Comment: Has anyone implemented B+Tree dispatch as an alternative to a dispatch table (in case the dispatch table gets bigger than the memory available)? Some have implemented Binary Tree dispatch but this is still memory bound. The advantage of B+Trees is that they overlap storage/memory and use the best of both worlds (fast lookups in memory and huge size but slow lookups of storage).

Comment: I can't possibly imagine a situation where your *dispatch table* would be so large that it couldn't be held in memory itself. You wouldn't have any space left for real work!

Answer (score 6):

In all likelihood, this will violate some internal constraint on the compiler. If there's a problem, you won't see the runtime.

The general way to solve this is to stop generating code like this. Don't bake this sort of data into the runtime. Instead, this should be some file format that is loaded and parsed into a hierarchy of class *instances*, not of classes themselves.

Answer (score 5):

> Isn't there a stack overflow danger when calling the top abstract class?

There certainly is. Each constructor and destructor will call its counterpart in the parent class, all the way up the hierarchy, generating a very deep call stack.

If it survives construction, then calling the virtual function will be fine - that's just a single function call to the final override.

> What strategies (other than ulimit -a or collapsing the abstract hierarchy) do C++ programmers use to work within system boundaries?

Personally, I tend to avoid inheritance altogether (except for abstract interfaces, and cases where I'm too lazy to encapsulate things nicely).

In this case, I might suggest a run-time hierarchy of objects, perhaps using function pointers to give a similar behaviour to virtual functions; the only constraint would be the memory needed to store them all. It's not as elegant as using the type system to represent your categories, but is less likely to run into implementation limits.

Comment: The compiler has its limits as well.  I suspect that a class hierarchy deep enough to cause stack problems at runtime would exceed the compiler limits.  (From a design point of view, of course: I can conceive of a few cases where four or five deep would be reasonable.  More than that: only in machine generate code.)

Answer (score 1):

Try that and see for yourself ;)

```
template <int i>
class oferflowMe: public overflowMe<i-1>{
    ....
};

template <>
class oferflowMe<1>{
    ....
};
```

Comment: There's an implementation-defined template instantiation limit, which typically is a lot lower. C++03 advised "at least 17"!

Comment: @MSalters I've seen people doing static calculations using templates, like summing numbers from 1 to 100. It seemed to work quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Not in this simple case. However, if you have multiple virtual inheritance, then some compilers will use "adjustor thunks" to fix `this`. These small functions will end up on your call stack.

Comment: The compiler will use those thunks, but will those stay on the stack? I think it rather works a bit like tail-call - function is being called, and disappears from stack when calling it's last function. Anyway, are those thunks even proper functions?